# S3: how to upload large number of files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have to upload 100k small files (Total size: 200MB).

I've tried to do that via web browser (AWS Console), but for the first 15 min, i've uploaded only 2MB.

What is the fastest way to upload 100k small files to S3?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have 99,561 small files totalling 466MB and experimented with uploading these to S3 as quickly as possible from my `m4.16xlarge` (64 CPU) EC2 instance.

- `aws s3 sync` took 10 minutes
- CyberDuck promised to take 17 minutes, but hung. I terminated it after 45 minutes.
- CloudBerry seems to be windows only at first glance, so I did not test it.
- `s3-parallel-put --put=stupid` took 9 minutes
- `s3-parallel-put --put=stupid --processes=64` took 1 minute
- `s3-parallel-put --put=stupid --processes=256` took 19 seconds
- `s3-parallel-put --put=stupid --processes=512` took 18 seconds

I'll be moving forward with a `s3-parallel-put` solution.

Comment: Used this to upload on digital ocean spaces

`./s3-parallel-put --bucket=ililililili --bucket_region=nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com --grant=public-read --host=nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com --prefix=test/upload/ --put=stupid --processes=30 --content-type=guess --log-filename=./s3pp.log ./uploads/`

Comment: This was extremely helpful.  Even just with the aws s3 sync option, that was good enough for me.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but none of these worked to copy from my local computer on MacOS. `aws s3 sync` hung and `s3-parallel-put` is Linux-only.

Answer (score 14):

Install [the AWS CLI tool](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), then use the `aws s3 cp` command or the `aws s3 sync` command to upload all your files to S3.

Alternatively you could look into using third-party S3 clients such as [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/?l=en) and [CloudBerry Explorer](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/explorer/amazon-s3.aspx).

Comment: I've used `aws s3 cp` with following command: `aws s3 cp myDir s3://mybucket/ --recursive`. More details: [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html). And it took me approx: 3 min to upload 100k files with total size 200MB

Comment: I've used this boto3 function [boto3.s3.transfer](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boto3/s3/transfer.html) to upload (multipart transfers) some db backup file to s3, but in my case I had to compress the files first. Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, a command line tool that worked for me to sync a folder with more than 600 000 files (totalling 4 GB) is `s4cmd`:

```
brew install s4cmd
s4cmd sync /path/to/local/folder s3://your-s3-bucket/path
```

I was not able to use `s3-parallel-put`, because this tool is Linux-only.

I normally use `aws s3 sync` or `aws s3 cp`, but these only resulted in heavy system resource utilization without any visible progress.